# How to make editable TextBox with WinAPI?

Tags: c++, winapi, textbox

I just switched from Winforms and everything looks so hard for me. I facing one problem after another. The next one, is...

```
#ifndef ActivationWindow_h
#define ActivationWindow_h

#include <windows.h>

class ActivationWindow
{
    static HWND main_wnd;
    static HWND lbl_login_desc;
    static HWND txt_login;

public:
    static void CreateWnd()
    {
        MSG msg = { 0 };
        WNDCLASS wc = { 0 }; 
        wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
        wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
        wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BACKGROUND);
        wc.lpszClassName = "actwnd";

        if(!RegisterClass(&wc))
            return;

        if(!(main_wnd = CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName, "Program activation", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 640, 480, 0, 0, wc.hInstance, NULL)))
            return;

        lbl_login_desc = CreateWindow("static", "ST_U", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, 10, 10, 50, 20, main_wnd, (HMENU)(501), wc.hInstance, NULL);
        SetWindowText(lbl_login_desc, "Login: ");

        txt_login = CreateWindow("edit", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | ES_LEFT | WS_BORDER, 70, 10, 50, 20, main_wnd, (HMENU)(502), wc.hInstance, NULL);

        while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
            DispatchMessage( &msg );
    }

    static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        switch(message)
        {
            case WM_CLOSE:
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                break;

            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }

        return 0;
    }  
};

HWND ActivationWindow::main_wnd = NULL;
HWND ActivationWindow::lbl_login_desc = NULL;
HWND ActivationWindow::txt_login = NULL;

#endif ActivationWindow_h
```

When window is shown, I can't type any characters into TextBox. How to do it?

Also, if I move mouse pointer to that TextBox it becomes "I", if I move mouse out to the window, the mouse pointer is still "I", instead of arrow.
how do I fix that?

I see some questions regarding that, but the guy telling he disabled DirectInput 8 and everything worked out. i don't know what I using...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `TranslateMessage` in your message loop or `WM_CHAR` messages won't be generated.

Your cursor stays an I-Beam because you aren't setting the cursor in your window class. What reference are you learning from that doesn't show the basic window class registration that sets the cursor to `LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW)` and the icon to `LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION)`?

Comment: I did say where...inside the message loop. The `while (GetMessage...` part is the message loop.

Comment: I meant where xactly? I can call it before DispatchMessage( &msg );, after that or inside WndProc In many cases or default... I am really don't understand how it works

Comment: Before `DispatchMessage`...I have to ask again, what resource are you learning from that doesn't show you this?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/215690/Minimal-WinApi-Window Learning from here :P

Comment: That isn't a good tutorial, it seems to me, although even it does mention `TranslateMessage` and `WM_CHAR` if you read through it.

Comment: I see what the author was going for, but that tutorial teaches you lots of things you are going to have to unlearn, so I don't see the benefit, really. Notably, all that "advanced" stuff the article complains about in the Visual C++ generated file is different from the article's code in that your edits probably would have worked without all the confusion. Windows API programming is overwhelming at first, especially because all the API-specific types are strange looking, but once you get the hang of it it's not so bad.

Comment: Well, if edits were worked, I never knew why they work :D But thanks for explaining this things for me.

Comment: A good tutorial like Charles Petzold's Programming Windows 5th Edition (note 5th not 6th which is C# and Windows 8 stuff, not WinAPI) would explain all the boilerplate stuff to you and walk you through to more advanced stuff. If you are willing to shell out the cash for it, it's available on Amazon for like $28 in a Kindle edition.

Comment: Just be aware that Petzold's book is a little dated at this point. Most importantly, it's not 64-bit ready. But it still covers the basics pretty well.

Comment: Thank you. I can't say I will start reading it right now, but it the good place to start if I got more problems, which will happen for sure.